# Config::Simple and constant assignation in perl

Tags: perl, constants, config, configuration-files, ini

I am using the `Config::Simple` module and the `constant` pragma. I am parsing a configuration file and setting the values as constant. the test configuration file (`test.ini`) contains:

```
POP3SERVER='192.168.1.1'
```

when I am running the follow perl statements:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Config::Simple;
my %Cnf;
Config::Simple->import_from('test.ini', \%Cnf);
use constant TEST => scalar $Cnf{"default.POP3SERVER"};
print $Cnf{"default.POP3SERVER"},"\n";
print TEST . "\n";
```

I get the following lines:

```
192.168.1.1
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./algo.pl line 10.
```

The hash contains the information, you can see it in the first `print` but when assigned in the `constant` statement is not set

What am I doing wrong on the code??

thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"use" happens at compile time, calling import_from() happens at run time (ie *after* the use).

Wrap the call to import_from in a BEGIN block:

```
my %Cnf;
BEGIN {
    Config::Simple->import_from('test.ini', \%Cnf);
}
use constant TEST => scalar $Cnf{"default.POP3SERVER"};
```